# How to Sum a column, when another column = 'Accepted' (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently looking to sum a column, if another column meets the requirements.

In this case I want to Sum the total of [Weight] if [Status]='Accepted' shipment.I have looked everywhere and I haven't made much progress. Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
CASE WHEN [Status:  Accepted, Pending, Rejected] = 'ACCEPTED' 
        THEN SUM(([Weight (lbs)]))  END ) AS ACCEPT_WEIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` is the argument to the `sum()`, like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [Status: Accepted, Pending, Rejected] = 'ACCEPTED' THEN [Weight (lbs)] 
    END) AS ACCEPT_WEIGHT
```

If you want to ensure that the value is never `NULL`, then use an `ELSE` clause:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [Status: Accepted, Pending, Rejected] = 'ACCEPTED' THEN [Weight (lbs)] 
         ELSE 0
    END) AS ACCEPT_WEIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  sum()  outisde the case condition eg:

```
sum( CASE WHEN [Status:  Accepted, Pending, Rejected] = 'ACCEPTED' 
    THEN [Weight (lbs)] ELSE 0  END ) AS ACCEPT_WEIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN T.[Status] = 'ACCEPTED' THEN T.[Weight (lbs)] ELSE 0  END ) AS ACCEPT_WEIGHT FROM YOURTABLE AS T
```

Hope this helps!